# add event to calender view sharepoint programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to add an event to a specific view in my SharePoint calender.
With this code I succeeded to add it, but to the default SharePoint calender:

```
SPListItem newEvent = list.Items.Add();
newEvent["Location"] = c.location;
newEvent["Heure de début"] = c.start;
newEvent["Heure de fin"] = c.end;
newEvent["Description"] = c.Description;
newEvent["Titre"] = c.Title;
newEvent.Update();
```

How can I proceed to add those informations to one specific view?
I have done this but it doesn't work

```
SPView m_view = list.Views["Mon calendrier Outlook "];
m_view.CalendarSettings = SerializeAccessors();
m_view.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add events to specific view, however.. You can lets say have a new Field named "Category" and in the VIEW, filter the events based on Category..

Let's say you want to show All Seminars, than you have a category named "Seminar".. In the view just filter the values based on Category field with value "Seminar"